# Wine; No JVM could be found

Tags: wine

I recently installed Wine and it has been working fine.  This afternoon I try and fire up a .exe program I had up and running hours before and was hit with this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ki9N.png) message.  Does anyone know the remedy for this problem?

Comment: What did you do to the system between when it worked and it didn't work?

Comment: Went to work.  (Absolutely nothing)

Comment: Automatic updates?

Comment: Yes, and I have JDK installed.